# How do I store the Directory name chosen from FolderBrowserDialog() in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, messagebox

I have a "settings" button in one of my programs that will be used to grab a directory that the user wants to work with.

After they select a directory, I'd like to be able to return three pieces of information.

1. The name of the directory chosen.
2. The number of files in that directory (just files, not other directories)
3. A list with the names of every file in the directory.

I have been looking through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) page, and I found the GetFiles() method, but I haven't figured out how to get the name of the directory.  Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Here's what I have so far.

```
public void SettingsButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);
            MessageBox.Show("files found" + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
        }
    }
```

I know the code above doesn't return the names of the files, but I know the rough idea on how to do that, I just haven't implemented it yet....so my questions just about storing the directory they chose as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example how you can do this, a simple foreach:

```
    public void SettingsButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {    
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);

                string resultStr = string.Empty;
                foreach (String item in files)
                {
                    resultStr += item.ToString() + "\n";
                }

                MessageBox.Show("path:" + dialog.SelectedPath + "\n" + 
                                "files: " + files.Count().ToString() + "\n" + 
                                 resultStr, "Message");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
FolderBrowserDialog() dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Here result will have the selected folder.

Comment: That's almost exactly the code I have in the question, which is fine, but I'm not sure how to get the selected folder out of result.  If I add MessageBox.Show(result); it returns OK...which is what I thought it should, but that's definitely not the selected folder.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to get the selected folder out of result?  In the form of a messagebox or anything else?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(dialog.SelectedPath.ToString());